# Frequency analysis for simultaneous dice rolls

Tags: performance, perl, dice, data-visualization

My professor told me to optimize my perl code, but he wouldn't tell me what exactly - just make it simpler.

I changed some little things but nothing major. Am I missing something?

The task was:

> Perl program that allows the user to simulate the simultaneous
>   throwing of several cubes. The simulation result is then a total
>   number of points, which is the sum of the numbers of the eyes results
>   in single throws. If many of these throws are performed with several
>   cubes, the frequency distribution for the total number of eyes is
>   calculated. This frequency distribution should be in the console
>   window in the form of a table and as a simple overview chart.
>
> At the beginning the following entries should be requested by the
>   user:
>
> - the number of dice he wants to roll.
> - the number of throws he wants to perform with the selected number of dice.
>
> The frequency distribution for the total number of eye sets should be
>   displayed in two different ways:
>
> - Tabular representation as a comparison of the number of points obtained and the associated frequency, both the absolute values ​​of
>     the frequency and the normalized values ​​that result in the division 
>     of the absolute values ​​resulting from the total number of throws are
>     issued.
> - Graphic representation as a simple (tilted by 90 degrees) bar chart (e.g. corresponding number of *)
>
> Use subroutines.

```
use warnings;                   
use diagnostics;                
use GD::Graph::hbars;        
use GD;
use List::Util qw(max);
my $number_of_dice = 0;   
my $number_of_rolls  = 0;     
my $sum_of_throw = 0;     
my @total_sum_of_eyes;       
my @single_sum_of_eyes;   
my @frequency;            
my %count;                   
my $count =0;                 
my $number =0;                

print "\n Please insert the number_of_dice: ";   
chomp($number_of_dice=<STDIN>);
print "\n Please instert the number_of_rolls: ";
chomp($number_of_rolls=<STDIN>);


while ($count< $number_of_rolls) {                  
    roll($number_of_dice);                      
    push(@total_sum_of_eyes,$sum_of_throw);     
    $count++;                                           
}  
frequency();                        
representation ();


sub roll{ 
    $sum_of_throw = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i< $number_of_dice; $i++)      
    {
        $number = int(rand(6) +1);                  
        $sum_of_throw+=$number;                     
    }
}

sub frequency{
    foreach my $eyes(sort{$a <=> $b} @total_sum_of_eyes){                       
        $count{$eyes}++;
    } 
}
sub representation{
    #Tabular representation
    print "\n the frequencys-distribution is: \n";
    print "\n total_sum_of_eyes\t frequency\t frequencys-distribution in %\n";
    foreach my $eyes (sort{$a <=> $b} keys %count){         
        push(@frequency, $count{$eyes});                #data for the bar chart     
        push(@single_sum_of_eyes, $eyes);               #data for the bar chart         
        printf "\n\t $eyes\t\t\t  $count{$eyes}\t\t%g",($count{$eyes}/$number_of_rolls)*100;
    }
    print "\n";
    #bar chart
    my $graph = GD::Graph::hbars->new(1600, 600);       
$graph->set(                                            
    x_label             => 'total_sum_of_eyes',         
    y_label             => 'frequency',             
    title               => 'frequencys-distribution',   
    y_max_value         =>  max(@frequency)+1,          
    y_min_value         =>  0,                          
    y_tick_number       => 8,                           
    transparent         => 0,                           
    bgclr               => 'white',                     
    long_ticks          => 1,                           
) or die $graph->error;                                 
my @data = (\@single_sum_of_eyes,\@frequency);      
$graph->set( dclrs => [ qw(green) ] );   
my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;  
open(IMG, '>gd_bars.gif') or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $gd->gif;
}
```

Comment: Use smallest possible scope for `my` variables. Also pass variables to functions as arguments, and use `return $var` to return result from functions. This is not perl specific but applies to almost every language. That sort for `$count{$eyes}++` doesn't do anything useful. Use simpler, perl specific loops, `for (1 .. $number_of_rolls)`

Comment: Dont use same variable names for `$count`, and `%count`.

Answer (score 2):

The code can be simplified.

It would be better to move some of the variables from the main scope into the subroutines.  For example, the `roll` sub can take an input value and return a value.   Then, the return value can be used directly as a key to the `%count` hash.

If you change the `while` to a `for` loop, that eliminates the need for the `$count` variable.  This, combined with the change to `roll`, eliminates the need for the `frequency` subroutine and the `sort` therein.

You should use `strict` instead of `diagnostics`.  The latter should only be used for temporary debugging.

### Indentation

The `representation` subroutine is missing indentation for the bar chart code.

### Output formatting

I think `%f` is more apt than `%g` in this context.  Also, there is no need for as many digits of precision; 2 should suffice after the decimal point (`%.2f`).

### Typos

`instert` should be `insert`.

`frequencys` is not a word.  I would just use `frequency` in the output.

### Style

`for` is simpler than `foreach`.

Add space between control keywords (`if`, `while`) and the opening paren `(`.

Add space around operators, and 1 space after commas.

Use the range operator (`..`) instead of the C-style `for` loops.

There is no need for parentheses with your `push` builtins.

Trailing whitespace is not needed and can be annoying.  Just remove it.

Use `exit` to separate the main code from the subroutines.

### Input checking

Consider adding code to check the inputs to make sure they are numbers (instead of words, for example) and that they are in reasonable ranges.  Refer to [looks_like_number](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util#looks_like_number).

### Documentation

Consider adding some usage notes at the top of the file as plain old documentation ([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)), something as simple as:

```
=pod

Roll the dice...

=cut
```

---

Here is new code with some of the suggestions above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);
use GD::Graph::hbars;
use GD;

my $number_of_dice;
my $number_of_rolls;
my %count;

print "\n Please insert the number_of_dice: ";
chomp($number_of_dice = <STDIN>);
print "\n Please insert the number_of_rolls: ";
chomp($number_of_rolls = <STDIN>);

for (1 .. $number_of_rolls) {
    $count{ roll($number_of_dice) }++;
}

representation();
exit;

sub roll {
    my $number_of_dice = shift;
    my $sum_of_throw = 0;
    for (1 .. $number_of_dice) {
        $sum_of_throw += int(rand(6) + 1);
    }
    return $sum_of_throw;
}

sub representation {
    my @frequency;
    my @single_sum_of_eyes;

    # Tabular representation
    print "\n the frequency-distribution is: \n";
    print "\n total_sum_of_eyes\t frequency\t frequency-distribution in %\n";
    for my $eyes (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count) {
        push @frequency, $count{$eyes};     # data for the bar chart
        push @single_sum_of_eyes, $eyes;    # data for the bar chart
        printf "\n\t $eyes\t\t\t  $count{$eyes}\t\t%.2f", ($count{$eyes}/$number_of_rolls)*100;
    }
    print "\n";

    # Bar chart
    my $graph = GD::Graph::hbars->new(1600, 600);
    $graph->set(
        x_label             => 'total_sum_of_eyes',
        y_label             => 'frequency',
        title               => 'frequencys-distribution',
        y_max_value         =>  max(@frequency)+1,
        y_min_value         =>  0,
        y_tick_number       => 8,
        transparent         => 0,
        bgclr               => 'white',
        long_ticks          => 1,
    ) or die $graph->error;
    my @data = (\@single_sum_of_eyes,\@frequency);
    $graph->set( dclrs => [ qw(green) ] );
    my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;
    open(IMG, '>gd_bars.gif') or die $!;
    binmode IMG;
    print IMG $gd->gif;
}
```